# Wait for class variable change with threading

Tags: python, multithreading, multiprocessing, wait

I have tried the following code snippets. It exists in two separate `.py` files `ChrMain.py` and `xlWingsTest.py`
The meaning is to wait in the main code until excel trigger the class value to True. The code gives no errors but it doesn't trigger the main code. I don't like to use sleep in the code. The main code is already running when excel and xlWings execute the trigger.

***Main Code***

```
from waiting import wait as Wait
import time
import threading

class RunSub:
    RunNu = False

class RunMain:
    isRun = True

def ChrMain():
    while RunMain.isRun:
        try:
            print('Sub is waiting')
            Wait(lambda : RunSub.RunNu, timeout_seconds = 40)
            print('Sub is continueing ...')
            # Do other Stuff
            time.sleep(5) # This line is only for testing
            RunMain.isRun = False
        except:
            pass

m = threading.Thread(name = 'Main', target = ChrMain())
m.start()
print('Program End')
exit()


***Trigger Code***


import xlwings as xw

def SetRunNow(myBool):
    if myBool:
        RunSub.RunNu  = True
    else:
        RunSub.RunNu = False

def StopProg(myBool):
    if myBool:
        RunMain.isRun = True
    else:
        RunMain.isRun = False

@xw.func
def Injector(myBool, strfunctie):
    import threading
    if strfunctie == 'SetRunNow':
        from ChrMain import RunSub
        i = threading.Thread(name = 'RunNow', target = SetRunNow(myBool))
        i.start()
        i.join()
        return RunSub.RunNu
    elif strfunctie == 'StopProg':
        from ChrMain import RunMain
        i = threading.Thread(name = 'StopProg', target = StopProg(myBool))
        i.start()
        i.join()
        return RunMain.isRun
    #exit()
```

Answer (score 0):

This line might have a bug: `i = threading.Thread(name = 'RunNow', target = SetRunNow(myBool))`

`target` must be a function, but `SetRunNow(myBool)` is a boolean.
a way to fix this would be:

`i = threading.Thread(name = 'RunNow', target = lambda: SetRunNow(myBool))`

Comment: Hi Rene, thanks for the answer. I modified the code but the problem is not solved.
It don't trigger the Main code Wait(.....)